# Large data frame column not being rounded [R]

Tags: r, rounding, digits

I have a large data frame of coordinates (`phi`, `r`, `z`). I want every `phi` value to be rounded to the nearest integer.

The data is arranged as a data frame, `df.cyl`, of three columns; `phi`, `r`, and `z`. There are 6,828,021 obs. of the three variables. `phi` has values ranging from 0 to 360 with up to 5 decimal digits per entry.

I tried to round the `phi` column in the following way:

```
mat.cyl <- as.matrix(df.cyl)
round(mat.cyl[,'phi'], digits = 0)
df.cyl <- as.data.frame(mat.cyl)
```

However, this appears to have no effect on the `phi` column; it appears identically as before these three lines.

I feel like I must be making a mistake somewhere, or misunderstanding the `round()` function. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

We need to do an assignment

```
mat.cyl[, 'phi'] <- round(mat.cyl[,'phi'], digits = 0)
```

Comment: Or with $ notation: `mat.cyl$phi <- round(mat.cyl$phi, digits = 0)`